# Show linked products using wp query and woocommerce

Tags: wp-query, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

Cannot find any information anywhere about pulling the linked products?

I need to create a custom query to load the linked products but could only find related.

Any information?

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for

```
get_cross_sells()
```